# pivot table second level =GetPivotData

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a data set that consists of efficiency metrics with a heirarchy assigned. That heirarchy goes from LOCATION > MANAGER > EMPLOYEE. I have a pivot table created that puts the data in that order in the ROW LABELS. The Values are the effeciency metrics.

I have a =GETPIVOTTABLE formula created to pull back information on each EMPLOYEE, and LOCATION but I am unable to get it to generate subtotals for the MANAGER because the pivot is fully expanded down to the employee. If I collapse the pivot, it will then give me the subtotal for the manager.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of TIMEWORKED",'4'!$B$13,"MANAGERName",$C3305)
```

Is there a way to for the =GETPIVOTDATA forumla to pull back totals for all 3 levels in the heirarchy?

Comment: Will post what your pivot table looks like?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the actual data, but let me see if I can post a mock up for reference.

Comment: Figured it out.... the damn subtotal wasn't turned on. For those with the same issue, simply go into the field settings and select subtotal-automatic instead of none. D'oh!